# Do you need a personal statement in CV

Tags: software-industry, resume, united-kingdom

For some countries, like UK, people include a personal statement in their CVs. However, I've been told that I should keep my CV short and sweet, and no more than one page. So, What should I do? Or should I put it in a cover letter or an E-mail?

Answer (score 2):

CV objective #1: Avoid being put on the "No" pile. HR needs to easily recognize that you're a match for the position. Basically don't do any of the things that are wrong.

CV objective #2: Manage being selected for an interview from the rest. The manager should want you more that the others. Basically do as many things as possible of the things that are right.

A personal statement tends to help more in step 2 than step 1. So if you want to include it you need to ensure that objective 1 is still achieved. A CV doesn't HAVE to stick to one page. But each page has to convince the person reading it that it is worth continuing.

Also strongly consider whether your personal statement enhances your image or merely adds "personality" aka noise.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a reasonably large tech company. We get CVs from a bunch of different countries so we're used to seeing different formats. I've had everything from one-page CVs to 12-page academic lists of publications. I wouldn't notice or worry about the absence of a personal statement.

I don't include a personal statement on my CV. No need to *claim* X when I've got a bunch of real-world experience *showing* X.

With regards to length in general, two pages is an acceptable length for a CV in the UK. It's good to keep things succinct, but you shouldn't cut things down so far you omit the experience/skill that might get you the job.